# Novice coder question - JS User-generated shopping list - How to update number property of list objects and avoid duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, duplicates, user-input

e.g. if a user submits "tacos" twice, instead of having two lines, each containing "tacos", I want to have one line with "tacos x 2". Question 2 - is it possible to create a variable that selects every item in an array except another variable? e.g.

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{let j = !i;
}
```

(I am aware the above code is incorrect, I included it only to illustrate my question)

Thank you in advance.

```
 // key function out of context
 if (!items.includes(item.text)) {
 items.push(item);
 } else {
  items.item.number =+1
 }


 //entire html file with script including key function in context

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>LocalStorage</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>


 <div class="wrapper">
 <h2>LOCAL TAPAS</h2>
 <p></p>
 <ul class="plates">
  <li>Loading Tapas...</li>
 </ul>
 <form class="add-items" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Item Name" required>
  <input type="submit" value="+ Add Item">
 </form>
 <button type="reset" value="reset"">clear all</button>
 <button class="select">Select all</button>
 </div>

 <script>

 const addItems = document.querySelector('.add-items');
 const itemsList = document.querySelector('.plates');
 const selectAll = document.querySelector('.select');
 const items = [];
 const mySet = new Set();
 const userInput = document.querySelector('[type="text"]');
 // add items to list

 // populate list with html

  function add(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.dir(e.currentTarget)
  const text = e.currentTarget.item.value;

  const item = {
    text,
    done:false,
    number: 1,
  };

  console.dir(item)

  
 if (!items.includes(item.text)) {
 items.push(item);
 } else {
 items.item.number =+1
 }



  e.currentTarget.reset();

  itemsList.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('itemsUpdated'))

  }

 function displayItems(item, i) {
 const html = items.map((item, i) => `
 <li>
 <input type="checkbox">
 <label name="${item}" id="${i}"><strong>${item.text}</strong> x${item.number}             </label>
</li>`).join('');

itemsList.innerHTML = html;

};






  addItems.addEventListener('submit', add)
 itemsList.addEventListener('itemsUpdated', displayItems)



 </script>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: `items` appears to be an array, while `item` is an object so `items.item.number =+1` is invalid. You'd likely need to update it by its index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with how you're checking if your `item` object is in the `items` array.

Since the elements of your array are objects, you would need to modify that checkup - `includes` and `indexOf` won't work.

What you would need to do is:

```
let indx = items.findIndex(element => element.text === item.text);
```

[`array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) will let you find an element within an array which satisfies the given condition. In this case, you want to find a specific product by name. That's why we're doing the `element.text === item.text` comparison.

Check the updated example below, to see it in action.

```js
const addItems = document.querySelector('.add-items');
const itemsList = document.querySelector('.plates');
const selectAll = document.querySelector('.select');
const items = [];
const mySet = new Set();
const userInput = document.querySelector('[type="text"]');
// add items to list
// populate list with html

function add(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const text = e.currentTarget.item.value;

    const item = {
        text,
        done:false,
        number: 1,
    };

    /* these are the key changes */
    let indx = items.findIndex(element => element.text === item.text);

    if (indx < 0) {
        items.push(item);
    } else {
        items[indx].number += 1;
    }
    /* */

    e.currentTarget.reset();
    itemsList.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('itemsUpdated'))
}

function displayItems(item, i) {
    const html = items.map((item, i) => `
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label name="${item}" id="${i}"><strong>${item.text}</strong> x${item.number}</label>
        </li>
    `).join('');

    itemsList.innerHTML = html;
};

addItems.addEventListener('submit', add)
itemsList.addEventListener('itemsUpdated', displayItems)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>LocalStorage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>LOCAL TAPAS</h2>
        <p></p>
        <ul class="plates">
            <li>Loading Tapas...</li>
        </ul>
        <form class="add-items" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Item Name" required>
            <input type="submit" value="+ Add Item">
        </form>
        <button type="reset" value="reset">clear all</button>
        <button class="select">Select all</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT** There were also minor syntax error edits:

- in your original code, your reset button had this as its value - `value="reset""`. I've removed the extra quote.
- your initial incrementing of `item.number` was also erroneous - instead of `items.item.number =+1` it should have been (as it is now) `items[indx].number += 1`. Note that it's `+=` and not `=+`.

Comment: Thank you so much, FiddlingAway! And apologies for the sloppy syntax errors.

Comment: @saulthompson Hey, don't worry about the mistakes, that's completely normal. What happened to your other question (a follow-up to this one)?

Comment: I had reputation points taken away for not being specific in my question title and description, so I deleted it. I think my question was too vague. I came up with a solution for another problem, but I'm sure my code was very inefficient, so I wanted to know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: But nor do I want to abuse the generosity of kind people like yourself with lazy and not particularly crucial questions, so it's probably for the best I just delete it. Thanks!